# Storing a php integer array

Tags: sql, arrays, serialization

I need to store an array of ints. Now my issue is, there's an operation that's done quite a few times so I'd like to limit it to one single query. In tha query, I would need to add an int to a certain int from the array.

It's for a timer of the time spent on a certain page. Currently it's just a general counter that counts for all the pages in the same field, so I only have to do

```
UPDATE user SET active = active+$totaltime WHERE id=:id
```

with the $totaltime being the time difference between last check and then. Now I'd like to store for certain pages seperately. The problem is I don't know exactly how many pages there will be. I thought about using [serialize](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), but then I'd need to do 2 queries a lot of times which doesn't seem like a good solution.

Are there any other methods to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a separate table for the levels which keeps track of active time associated with each user on each level.

Lets calls this table *userlevels*, and give it the following columns:

```
userid INT
levelid INT
active INT
```

The primary key should be a combination of the *userid* and *leveid* columns, since there can only be one entry for a particular combination of user and level.

Then when you want to update the amount of time a user has spent on a certain level, you would do something like:

```
INSERT INTO userlevels (userid,levelid,active)
VALUES (:userid,:levelid,$totaltime)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active=active+$totaltime;
```

This creates a new entry in the table if the user has never been on that level before, or adds to the active time if there is already an entry.

This is mysql specific syntax, but the same thing can be achieved on other databases with different calls.

Comment: Not really what I was looking for - my table is a list of users, and each user should somehow have stored how much time they spent in each level of a certain game. I presume having a column per level would be quite silly, but I don't know how to be able to add values in a single query if you have multiple values in one field, stored as a `serialised`-version or just storing the array as plain text.

Comment: Whilst mowing the lawn I came to the same conclusion - that a separate db would indeed be best. Also allows me to easily incorporate pageviews or add other pages with their times as well. Thanks!